# C#: Inconsistent accessibility error within Unit Test Class

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, excel-interop

I have seen previous posts about Inconsistent accessibility errors but they have not been as specific as my case, or so I believe.

Here are my two errors:

```
'ConsoleApplication1.Reader' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'ConsoleApplication1.Reader' is less 
accessible than field 'UnitTestProject1.ReaderTest.reader'
```

The Reader class is public so I am not sure why the test class does not see that. I have multiple other tests that do not have this same problem, and all are set up the same way. As for the second error I believe if I fix the first one that one will be resolved as a consequence. Below I will attach a piece of the Reader class as well as the test class for it. Advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Created and tested by Alexander James Bochel. 
    /// Last Updated: 6/7/2017
    /// </summary>
    class Program
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// This will call the rest of the classes in the program. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args"> Command line arguments. </param>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            openFile(); 
        }




        public static void openFile()
        {
            Reader reader = new Reader(@"C:\Users\abochel\Desktop\TEST.xlsx", 0);
        }

    }
} 



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Reader
    {
        public Reader()
        {
            // TODO - Default constructor. 
        }
    }
}

using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ConsoleApplication1;

namespace AutomationProgramTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ReaderTest
    {

        Reader reader;

        [TestMethod]
        public void testCreateSales()
        {
            reader = new Reader();  // TODO add path and sheet. 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] that we can copy/paste into Visual Studio to get the same error?  From what you've shown everything looks fine, but there are some pieces missing, such as the namespace that `Reader` is in.

Comment: @BJMyers I added the whole code! Thanks

Comment: This is still not a MCVE.  I can't copy/paste the code into my IDE and have it compile.  Remove everything that is not required to reproduce the problem, including class methods, references to external libraries (e.g. Excel interop), etc.

Comment: @BJMyers My apologies for not following your instructions the first time. My edited code is MCV.

Comment: @BJMyers I am running into a weird situation. In the code I gave you I get the error. When I remove the parameters from the reader line in the Main method in Program class I no longer get the error. When I re add the line I still no longer get the error. Does this have anything to do with the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this error by deleting the code in the constructor of the Reader class and the Reader initialization in the Main method. After reading these lines of code immediately after the program still worked even though nothing had truly changed. I am not sure why this worked but it did, and I successfully replicated it multiple times after deleting all code slowly until the error no longer occurred, allowing me to pinpoint the source.